# Greedy regex lookbehind

Tags: python, regex

I am writing a regex to grab data between `""`. The only issue I am running into is the last `"` is being captured. [Regex](https://regex101.com/r/BzQ36A/1)

```
  line = '<DT><A HREF="https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Clickjacking_Defense_Cheat_Sheet.html" ADD_DATE="1567455957">Clickjacking Defense · OWASP Cheat Sheet Series</A>'
  capture_regex = re.compile(r'(?<=HREF=").*?"',re.IGNORECASE)
  m = capture_regex.search(line)
```

`m.group()` prints `https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Clickjacking_Defense_Cheat_Sheet.html"`. How to write the regex where it does not include the last quotation mark.

Answered my question. I added I added what is called non-greedy to my regex.
`capture_regex = re.compile(r'(?<=HREF=").*?(?=")',re.IGNORECASE)`. By adding the `?` after `*` made it only stop at the first `"`.

Comment: Use a forward lookahead `(?=")` instead of just `"`

Comment: You should avoid using regex to parse HTML files. `bs4` should be used instead.

Comment: `(?=")` Looks for the last `"`. `bs4` would work, I am trying to improve me regex skills.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
capture_regex = re.compile(r'(?<=HREF=").*?(?=")',re.IGNORECASE)
```

[working fiddle](https://regex101.com/r/3JHdPq/2)

Edit: Adjusted the regex as it was too greedy. Thanks to @newdeveloper for pointing it out!

Comment: This is capturing more data than needed.  `https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Clickjacking_Defense_Cheat_Sheet.html" ADD_DATE="1567455957`

Comment: @newdeveloper: How stupid I missed that. It is corrected now...

Comment: Yeah I figured it out thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe, `find_all` from bs4 might work OK:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

line = '<DT><A HREF="https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Clickjacking_Defense_Cheat_Sheet.html" ADD_DATE="1567455957">Clickjacking Defense · OWASP Cheat Sheet Series</A>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(line, 'html.parser')

for l in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
    print(l['href'])
```

#### Output

```
https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Clickjacking_Defense_Cheat_Sheet.html
```

---

If not, maybe, some expression similar to

```
(?i)href="\s*([^\s"]*?)\s*"
```

with `re.findall` might be working here:

```
import re

expression = r'(?i)href="\s*([^\s"]*?)\s*"'

string = """
<DT><A HREF="https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Clickjacking_Defense_Cheat_Sheet.html" ADD_DATE="1567455957">Clickjacking Defense · OWASP Cheat Sheet Series</A>
<DT><A HREF=" https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Clickjacking_Defense_Cheat_Sheet.html " ADD_DATE="1567455957">Clickjacking Defense · OWASP Cheat Sheet Series</A>
"""

print(re.findall(expression, string))
```

#### Output

```
['https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Clickjacking_Defense_Cheat_Sheet.html', 'https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Clickjacking_Defense_Cheat_Sheet.html']
```

---

> If you wish to explore/simplify/modify the expression, it's been
>   explained on the top right panel of
>   [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/MyTQnz/1/). If you'd like, you
>   can also watch in [this
>   link](https://regex101.com/r/MyTQnz/1/debugger), how it would match
>   against some sample inputs.

---

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
import re

line = '<DT><A HREF="https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Clickjacking_Defense_Cheat_Sheet.html" ADD_DATE="1567455957">Clickjacking Defense · OWASP Cheat Sheet Series</A>'

capture_regex = re.compile(r'(?<=HREF=")([^"]*)(?:")',re.IGNORECASE)
# capture_regex = re.compile(r'(?:HREF=")([^"]*)(?:")',re.IGNORECASE) this will work too
print(capture_regex.search(line).groups())
# print(capture_regex.findall(line))  # if your text contains more than one HREF
```

Out put:

```
  ['https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Clickjacking_Defense_Cheat_Sheet.html']
```